# line race chart de Flourish Studio

Tags: google-chrome

Estoy haciendo unos gráficos en dicha página y no sé como hacer para que cuando ponga la opción "zoomed" a la hora de reproducir el gráfico no se trabe el gráfico por así decirlo, tampoco sé como explicarlo del todo bien, y me gustaría que si alguien puede ayudarme o contactarse conmigo por algún método le agradecería muchísimo